# My D-Link's Ethernet bridge downlink just got 10-30x slower?

Tags: networking, ethernet, performance

**TL;DR:** I unplugged my network to move my desk, and now downloading via my DIR-655's Ethernet LAN bridge is 10-30x slower than the Ethernet switch it's plugged into.

**Background**

My network is

```
SMC cable modem <-> Cisco firewall <-> Netgear switch <-> D-Link WiFi†
     |                    |                 |                  |
 SMC8014               ASA-5505         GS608v2 gigE      DIR-655 rev A3 gigE
```

†The DIR-655 is used as an access point, not a router (although what
D-Link calls an access point, I'd call a bridge). The "WAN" port is
unused; the Netgear connects to the built-in 4-port Ethernet LAN
switch, inside the built- in router/firewall.

Endpoints:

- MacBook Pro 17" mid-2010
- iPhone 4S
- Fedora 12 Linux server running reasonably fast dual-Athlon X2, VelociRaptors, etc.

All cables are <10 feet, mostly CAT-5e, some CAT-6, all premade. All WiFi endpoints are within three feet of the D-Link.

Yesterday I unplugged and rearranged stuff, and now connecting via the D-Link - even through the wired switch, right next to the incoming network cable - is 30x slower than connecting directly to the Netgear switch, on both my MacBook and iPhone.

**How I'm measuring "slower"**

I'm mostly using http://speedtest.net, which of course only really measures broadband speeds. I've also installed http://www.speedtest.net/mini.php on my local server, but can't test the iPhone with that.

**Results**

```
Speedtest.net, closest server over Comcast business-class:

CONFIG                           | PING (ms)   | DOWN (Mbps)   | UP (Mbps)
Mac    <-> Ethernet <-> Netgear  |  9          | 31.6          |  6.8 
Mac    <-> Ethernet <-> D-Link   |  8          |  4.1          |  6.0
Mac    <-> WiFi     <-> D-Link   |  9          |  1.4          |  2.9
iPhone <-> WiFi     <-> D-Link   | 67          |  0.4          |  1.6

Speedtest Mini on Linux PC:

CONFIG                                         | DOWN (Mbps)   | UP (Mbps)
Mac    <-> Ethernet <-> NetGear                | 97.2          | 76.9
Mac    <-> Ethernet <-> D-Link                 |  8.2          | 24.2
Mac    <-> WiFi     <-> D-Link                 |  1.0          |  8.6

Slow typing in SSH:

Mac    <-> Ethernet <-> Netgear <-> Linux PC: smooth
Mac    <-> Ethernet <-> D-Link  <-> Linux PC: choppy
```

Note that D-Link upload speeds are normal on broadband, slower locally (but I'd believe that's a D-Link limitation), and always faster than the downloads! Since ssh is choppy just with slow typing, I don't believe it's a throttling-type problem either; that's not a lot of bandwidth.

**What I've tried**

- Swapping all "good" and "bad" cables
- Re-plugging "bad" cable from D-Link to Netgear and watching it be the "good" cable
- pulling cables away from power lines
- Verify that the Mac auto-detects the D-Link as gigE
- Try to verify the link speed of the D-Link <-> Netgear connection, but the firmware doesn't report that
- Verify that the D-Link sees no TX/RX errors or collisions
- Use different Ethernet ports on both Netgear and D-Link
- Reset the D-Link to factory settings
- Upgrade the D-Link firmware from 1.21 to 1.35NA,  2010/11/12, the latest
- Reboot everything at least once
- On the Mac, disable Wi-Fi during the Ethernet tests, and unplug Ethernet during the Wi-Fi tests
- Using iStumbler, verify that the D-Link isn't picking overloaded Wi-Fi channels (usually just 1-5 neighbors on my and adjacent channels, average for my apt building)
- Verify that the only client connected to the Wi-Fi was the iPhone
- Verify that nothing was being chatty on my network according to the WISH log
- Enable and disable all sorts of D-Link settings, including forcing WAN auto-detect to gigE

**So.**

I don't mind buying a new access point—I wouldn't mind having a dual-link network—but as a guy who's been networking since gated v4 was a drastic rewrite, and who often used physical sniffers in the days before Wireshark, I'm baffled. I hate being baffled.

What could I *possibly* have changed that would result in this? How can I measure it? All I can think of is a static zap—thick carpet, socks, HVAC—but I didn't feel one, and does that really happen anymore?

Can I test if it's Ethernet vs. TCP layer slowness? I'm not familiar with modern network utilities; it's hard to Google without hitting "Q: Why is my network slow? A: Is your microwave on?"

If I don't get an answer here, will someone big and powerful help me migrate it to serverfault without getting screamed back here?  In the words of Inigo Montoya, "I *must* know." Don't get all Dread Pirate Roberts on me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a netgear switch that had a "uplink" port that was actually shared between two interfaces. If you had something plugged into the port next to the uplink the speed would drop by an order of magnitude. I too have considerable network experience so I broke out tcpdump and really over-analyzed the hell out of it.

I moved the cable over one port, voila, speed returned. This affected wireless and wired clients. It was the most bizarre thing. I pulled the switch, tossed in a cisco 2548 and never had the problem again.

Unfortunately, I am not sure if they have ethtool or mii-tool or the standard *nix t-shooting tools.

SSH being choppy sounds like a nagles algorithm or slow-start type issue slowly releasing packets into the network. Have you confirmed that there really is no network congestion?

This sounds exactly like the issue I was having.

Comment: What's a good way to confirm that there's no network congestion? I assumed that in a modern switched network (w/no other clients!), there simply wouldn't be any. I grabbed a D-Link DAP-1522 access point and it's working fine, but I'm still curious..